# Kubernetes Service not able to loadbalance requests

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

We faced some issue in one of our environment.One of the Microservice have 4 pods in production.We obeserved that only one of the pod was serving request.and once the number of request increased,that particular pod was not able to server request.

Issue: why only one pod was serving request.

Requirement: how we can ensure each pod will get approx equal requests.it will be better if requests will be served in Round-Robbin fashion so that each pod can contribute to handling requests.

Note: is there any way to check which pod is serving request at a particular time slice

Comment: This should happen automatically if you have kubernetes deployment and service objects. Please do put up the relevant k8s spec files so that we can see.